# How can I install orion-ml?

Tags: pip, requirements.txt

The recommended method for installing orion-ml is via pip (e.g., pip install orion-ml) as stated in the github [README.md](https://github.com/signals-dev/Orion)

However, this simple command causes the error

```
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of baytune to determine which version is 
compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting baytune<0.3,>=0.2.3
  Using cached baytune-0.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
  Using cached baytune-0.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of mlblocks to determine which version is 
compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver 
with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort this run, you can press 
Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: 
https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of <Python from Requires-Python> to determine 
which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of orion-ml to determine which version is 
compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Cannot install orion-ml because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    mlprimitives 0.2.4 depends on tensorflow<2 and >=1.11.0
    mlprimitives 0.2.3 depends on tensorflow<2 and >=1.11.0
    mlprimitives 0.2.2 depends on tensorflow<2 and >=1.11.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

This tells us there is a version conflict. How can I resolve this? Thank you

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I'm having the same issue with the installation of orion-ml #orion_ml.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and found out that orion-ml only worked with Python >=3.6, <3.8, but I had Python 3.9.2 installed which ended up pullig orion-ml 0.1.0 which is a very old version. I uninstalled 3.9.2 and installed a version under Python 3.8 and it worked

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Anaconda:
   https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#download-section
2. Create a virtual environment with python version 3.7.(3.8.8 python makes an error installing "pip install orion-ml")
3. Run your python 3.7 virtual env.
4. pip install orion-ml : There's no error install "orion-ml" package.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate conda environment like:

```html
conda create --name orion python=3.7 # or 3.6
conda activate orion
```

and then install tensorflow using:

```html
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

This will get you rid of the tensroflow error.